# logical partition or primary partition

Tags: partitioning

Today I was setting up an ubuntu server and while partitioning for RAID0 I wound up setting /home as a logical partition. Basically the partitioner defaulted to that option and I hit return and the system was off on the installation.

Anyway, does it matter that /home is a logical partition instead of a primary partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not matter. Logical partitions allow you to have many partitions instead of a limit of 4 with MBR. Example:

> [part1 windows C][part2 windows
>   D][part3 Data][part4 Ubuntu LOGICAL -
>   Part 5,6,7 (/, Swap, and /home)]

There will be no difference. It is just designed to be flexible.

Comment: Sure, have fun with Ubuntu. :)